# Why does python's imp.reload() not delete old classes and functions?

Tags: python, object, python-3.x, module, reload

I just recognized that `imp.reload()` does not delete old classes and functions if they were deleted from the module's source file.

An Example:

```
:~$ python3
Python 3.2.3 (default, May  3 2012, 15:54:42) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(open("test.py").read())
# empty file
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
'__package__']
>>> print(open("test.py").read())                             
# new class A and B added
class A:                                                      
        pass                                                  

class B:                                                      
        pass

>>> import imp
>>> dir(imp.reload(test))
['A', 'B', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
'__package__']
>>> print(open("test.py").read())
# class A deleted
class B:
        pass

>>> dir(imp.reload(test))
['A', 'B', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
'__package__']
>>> import sys
>>> dir(sys.modules['test'])
['A', 'B', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__',
'__package__']
>>> sys.modules['test'].A
<class 'test.A'>
```

In the last lines you can see that there is a class object `A` although it was deleted from the modules source code. Why is this so? Is there a way to recognize such elements of a module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/imp.html#imp.reload):

> If the new version of a module does not define a name that was defined by the old version, the old definition remains. This feature can be used to the module’s advantage if it maintains a global table or cache of objects — with a try statement it can test for the table’s presence and skip its initialization if desired:
>
> ```python
> try:
>     cache
> except NameError:
>     cache = {}
> ```

So that's why. If you don't want those old objects there you can probably empty the module's dictionary before reloading. For example, here I will import `hashlib`, empty its dictionary, and reload it.

```python
import hashlib

for attr in dir(hashlib):
    if attr not in ('__name__', '__file__'):
        delattr(hashlib, attr)

hashlib = imp.reload(hashlib)
```

<sub>Poor `hashlib`.</sub>

Comment: Poor `hashlib`. I wonder if this is still safe (and sufficiently inclusive) with current versions of python.

Comment: @matanster: I don't think recent versions of Python have changed anything here, so this should still be fine. Doesn't make it any less hacky than it was before, though.

Comment: The latest Python 3.10.2 has reload `from importlib import reload`. You can simply do `delattr(test, 'A')` to remove the class A attribute after reloading the module test.